# Counting geometrical constraints by blowing-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, blowup

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and let $|D|$ be a complete linear system of divisors on $X$. For a given codimension-two locus $S$ within $X$, a natural question is: what is the dimension of the subspace of elements of $|D|$ which completely contain $S$? In terms of cohomologies, we are interested in the subset
$$
R := \Big\{ \gamma \in H^0 \big(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D) \big) ~ \big| ~ \gamma(p) = 0 ~\,\forall p \in S \Big\} \,.
$$
In full generality this is likely to be a very difficult problem. I am interested in the case that $S$ is smooth, connected, and irreducible. Introducing the blow-up $\pi_S: \hat{X} \to X$ of $X$ along $S$, with $E_S$ the exceptional divisor that projects to $S$, my question is whether the following isomorphism always holds,
$$
R \stackrel{?}{\cong} H^0\Big(\hat{X},\mathcal{O}_\hat{X}\big(\pi_S^*(D)-E_S \big) \Big) \,.
$$

The underlying intution is that, from the point of view of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ as the sheaf of functions $f$ with divisor class $(f) \geq -D$, the term $-E_S$ restricts the functions on $\hat{X}$ to those that vanish over $E_S$, which should be in correspondence with functions on $X$ that vanish over $S$. In the simple examples I've checked, this isomorphism appears to hold. But I'm not sure whether or not this is due to a special simplification in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this follows from the exact sequence
$$
0 \to H^0(X,I_S(D)) \to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D)) \to H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(D))
$$
and an isomorphism
$$
\pi_{S*}\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}(\pi_S^*(D) - E) \cong
\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes \pi_{S*}\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}(- E) \cong
\mathcal{O}_X(D) \otimes I_S \cong
I_S(D).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Am I right in thinking that $I_S(D)$ is precisely the object I'm trying to compute, i.e. what I called $R$ in my question? If so, the isomorphism in the second equation seems to essentially answer my question, but I'm not sure of the importance of the exact sequence in the first equation.

Comment: Not quite --- $I_S(D)$ is a coherent sheaf and $R$ is its space of global sections.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant to ask whether $R \cong H^0\big(X,I_S(D)\big)$. However I am still not sure of the importance of the exact sequence. It seems to me that once the isomorphism is established, it only remains to use that $H^0\big(X,\pi_{S*}\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}(\pi_S^*(D) - E)\big) \cong H^0\big(\hat{X},\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}(\pi_S^*(D) - E)\big)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need the exact sequence to establish the isomorphism.